# importing module pandas, module not found

Tags: modulenotfounderror

Python version 3.11.8
Pandas version 2.20
Visual Studio Code 1.86.1
Windows 10

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

data = pd.read_csv("50_states.csv")
print(data)
```

If I run the code above with the play icon (Run code) I get this is the output window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Documents\Python Projects\Test_day_25\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

But if I run (run python file) it works and prints (data) to the terminal window.

I've tried creating different venv's

uninstalling/reinstalling pandas.

starting new projects (opening new folders)

changing interpreters.

checked version compatability

tried disabling extensions

Comment: did you activate virtualenv and try it again?

Comment: Wouldn't changing interpreters mean you also need to install pandas for those interpreters' virtualenvs?

Comment: OK so....I just opened cmd prompt and installed pandas globally which fixed the issue in my VS code project. 
So something isn't right in the virtual environment setup. I tried re activating the venv and reinstalling pandas, selecting the right interpreter etc. still no idea